# Detect if bounding box is inside tile

Tags: python, python-3.x

To elaborate, I'm trying to find where the `object` in this case, touches or is in which tiles (`row`). I can't find a solution anywhere online and am frustrated trying to find one.

Desired output: 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 ,11

[image: .]

Comment: Can you post some code, and be more specific? we don't know how you wan't to accomplish this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You have the x and y of the bounding box. Just check which row is the top `x`, bottom `x`; which column is the left `y`, right `y`. Then, all the tiles in the columns and rows contain the object.